# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (64x3072 and 64x3072)

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to make an image detection neural network. The train data is loaded within a batch size of 64. After running this code I get the RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (64x3072 and 64x3072). It's confusing, because to me these 2 shapes/size seem like they're the same.
Can anyone help me find that error?

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, kernel_size=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 12, kernel_size=2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(12, 18, kernel_size=2)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(18, 768, kernel_size=2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64, 3072)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(3072, 7)


    def forward(self, x):
        print(x.size()) #1
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        print(x.size()) #2
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        print(x.size()) #3
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        print(x.size()) #4
        x = self.conv4(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        print(x.size()) #5
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        print(x.size()) #6
        x = self.fc2(x)
        print(x.size()) #7

        return torch.sigmoid(x)
```

The print outputs of the forward function are:

```
torch.Size([64, 1, 48, 48]) #1
torch.Size([64, 6, 23, 23]) #2
torch.Size([64, 12, 11, 11]) #3
torch.Size([64, 18, 5, 5]) #4
torch.Size([64, 768, 2, 2]) #5
```

So, I'm pretty sure the error is located somewhere in the x = x.view() line and the first fully-connected layer. But I can't get it running.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The shape of `x` at **#5** is `(64, 768, 2, 2)`, i.e. `3072` components per batch element. Yet `fc1` only expects `64` features. For instance, you could replace `fc1` and `fc2` with:

```
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3072, 64)
self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 7)
```

Then you would have:

- `x`'s shape at **#6** is `(64, 64)`
- `x`'s shape at **#7** is `(64, 7)`